# Undefined method on nested instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a project instance with a nested task. If i debug `project.task` i got what i expect:

```
# debug result
--- !ruby/object:Task
attributes:
  id: 1
  name: XYZ
```

If i want to debug project.task.name i got the error message "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass".

```
# this works
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <%= project.name %><br/>
    <%= debug project.task %>
<% end %>        


# this does not work
<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <%= project.name %><br/>
    <%= debug project.task.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Looks like there is at least one Project in your `@projects` that doesn't have a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one works because if you execute :

```
project.task
```

and there is a project but there is no task, you get nil.

However, when you execute :

```
project.task.name
```

You get an exception if task is nil, since it cannot find the name attribute. However, you can force it to return nil if a task is not there, by using the rails try method :

```
project.task.try(:name)
```